# Android - Google Map - Displaying lot of Markers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

After several days of searching with no real answers, I would come to ask for help here.

Indeed, we are currently developing an android application using a google map.

In some cases, we need to display 800 markers with a different icon.

First thing first we create our icon using the svg library until then no problem.

Then we transform our Picture object (object returned by the svg library) to a Bitmap to set our icon on the MarkerOptions object.

But if we are displaying ours 800 markers and then remove them and repeat the manipulation, after some time, the application crashes with an Out of Memory error.

Our list of Marker objects is always clear() when removes markers from the map.

The list of our MarkerOptions objects is retained to not having to regenerate the icons again.

So we tried several things:

- Store in a list of Marker objects to loop over and set to null all the objects and then clear() the list
- Store in a list of MarkerOptions objects to loop over and set to null all the objects and then clear() the list

Nothing happens, there is always the problem of OutOfMemory after some time.

Comment: have you try to use clustering ?

Comment: In fact, before clustering those markers we want to try to find a solution to display all of them. It's a solution, but the last solution ...

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

into your AndroidManifest file. And put all the icons you are using into **drawable-nodpi** folder.

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Hello Sandeep Singh,

In fact [code]android:largeHeap="true"[/code] is already set.

And as I told you my icon are not stored in some folder because I generate them on live using SVG librairy.